# AnyEvent::RabbitMQ issues with closed channels

Tags: perl, rabbitmq, message-queue, anyevent

I'm writing a master program for publishing message into a message queue ([RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)). The program is written in Perl 5 and is using [AnyEvent::RabbitMQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::RabbitMQ) for the communication to RabbitMQ.

The following minimal example (for the issue I ran into) will fail on a second command send via the same channel with the error "Channel closed".

```
use strictures 2;

use AnyEvent::RabbitMQ;

main();

############################################################################
sub main {
  _log( debug => 'main' );
  my $condvar = AnyEvent->condvar;
  my $ar      = AnyEvent::RabbitMQ->new;
  $ar->load_xml_spec;
  _log( debug => 'Connecting to RabbitMQ...' );
  $ar->connect(
    host            => 'localhost',
    port            => 5672,
    user            => 'guest',
    pass            => 'guest',
    vhost           => '/',
    timeout         => 1,
    tls             => 0,
    on_success      => sub { _on_connect_success( $condvar, $ar, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure', @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return', @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close', @_ ) },
  );
  $condvar->recv;
  $ar->close;
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_connect_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $new_ar ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Connected to RabbitMQ.' );
  _open_channel( $condvar, $new_ar );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _open_channel {
  my ( $condvar, $ar ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Opening RabbitMQ channel...' );
  $ar->open_channel(
    on_success => sub { _on_open_channel_success( $condvar, $ar, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_open_channel_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Opened RabbitMQ channel.' );
  _declare_queue( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _declare_queue {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declaring RabbitMQ queue...' );
  $channel->declare_queue(
    queue       => 'test',
    auto_delete => 1,
    passive     => 0,
    durable     => 0,
    exclusive   => 0,
    no_ack      => 1,
    ticket      => 0,
    on_success =>
      sub { _on_declare_queue_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_declare_queue_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declared RabbitMQ queue.' );
  _bind_queue( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _bind_queue {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Binding RabbitMQ queue...' );
  $channel->bind_queue(
    queue       => 'test',
    exchange    => '',
    routing_key => '',
    on_success => sub { _on_bind_queue_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_bind_queue_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Binded RabbitMQ queue.' );
  _log( info  => 'Master ready to publish messages.' );
  _publish_message( $condvar, $ar, $channel, 'Hello, world!' );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _publish_message {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel, $message ) = @_;
  _log( debug => "Publishing RabbitMQ message ($message)..." );
  $channel->publish(
    queue       => 'test',
    exchange    => '',
    routing_key => '',
    body        => $message,
    header      => {},
    mandatory   => 0,
    immediate   => 0,
    on_success =>
      sub { _on_publish_message_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
    on_ack          => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'ack',          @_ ) },
    on_nack         => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'nack',         @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_publish_message_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => "Published RabbitMQ message." );
  sleep 1;
  _publish_message( $condvar, $ar, $channel, 'Hello, world! Again ' . time );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _error {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $type, @error ) = @_;
  _log( error => sprintf '%s - %s', $type, join ', ', @error );
  $condvar->send( $condvar, $ar, $type, @error );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _log {
  my ( $level, $message ) = @_;
  my @time = gmtime time;
  $time[5] += 1900;
  $time[4] += 1;
  my $time = sprintf '%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d+00:00', @time[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ];
  my @caller0    = caller(0);
  my @caller1    = caller(1);
  my $subroutine = $caller1[3];
  $subroutine =~ s/^$caller0[0]:://;
  print STDERR "$time [$level] $message at $caller0[1] line $caller0[2] ($subroutine; from $caller1[1] line $caller1[2])\n";
  return;
}
```

This program should:

- connect to RabbitMQ
- opens a RabbitMQ channel
- declares a simpe queue (named "test")
- bind to that queue (named "test")
- publish a message ("Hello, world!")
- after successfull publishing the message wait a second and publish another message

This program (master program) should *not* consume messages. There are other programs out there to do this job.

The minimal example (see above) will produce the following output:

```
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] main at minimal.pl line 9 (main; from minimal.pl line 5)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] Connecting to RabbitMQ... at minimal.pl line 13 (main; from minimal.pl line 5)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] Connected to RabbitMQ. at minimal.pl line 36 (_on_connect_success; from minimal.pl line 22)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] Opening RabbitMQ channel... at minimal.pl line 44 (_open_channel; from minimal.pl line 37)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] Opened RabbitMQ channel. at minimal.pl line 58 (_on_open_channel_success; from minimal.pl line 46)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] Declaring RabbitMQ queue... at minimal.pl line 66 (_declare_queue; from minimal.pl line 59)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] Declared RabbitMQ queue. at minimal.pl line 88 (_on_declare_queue_success; from minimal.pl line 76)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [debug] Binding RabbitMQ queue... at minimal.pl line 96 (_bind_queue; from minimal.pl line 89)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [error] failure - Channel closed at minimal.pl line 155 (_error; from minimal.pl line 102)
2015-08-12T13:02:07+00:00 [error] close - Net::AMQP::Frame::Method=HASH(0x38fe1c8) at minimal.pl line 155 (_error; from minimal.pl line 50)
```

Why does `AnyEvent::RabbitMQ` or RabbitMQ itself closes the channel (not the connection or did I miss something)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the RabbitMQ server logs you will see something like this:

> {amqp_error,access_refused,"operation not permitted on the default exchange",'queue.bind'}

Apparently it doesn't let you bind a *queue* on the *default exchange*. So you need to declare and bind your own *exchange* first.

```
sub _declare_exchange {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declaring RabbitMQ exchange...' );
  $channel->declare_exchange(
    exchange        => 'testest',
    type            => 'fanout',
    on_success =>
      sub { _on_declare_exchange_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_declare_exchange_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declared RabbitMQ exchange.' );
  _bind_exchange( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _bind_exchange {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Binding RabbitMQ exchange...' );
  $channel->bind_exchange(
    source      => 'testest',
    destination => 'testest',
    routing_key => '',
    on_success => sub { _on_bind_exchange_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}
```

Once you've set those subs up, tell your program to use this custom exchange.

```
sub _on_open_channel_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Opened RabbitMQ channel.' );
  $channel->confirm;
  _declare_exchange( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}
```

The `$channel->confirm` is necessary to make RabbitMQ answer with a confirmation when you send a message to the queue. If you do not do that, the success handler will never get called because there are no success responses coming back.

Then in your `_bind_queue` you need to add the exchange to the `bind_queue()` call.

```
  $channel->bind_queue(
    queue       => 'test',
    exchange    => 'testest', # <-- here
    routing_key => '',
    # ...
  );
```

The same needs to be done in the `_publish_message` with the `publish()` call. There you should also replace the `on_ack` handler with something that actually deals with the acknowledgement. I think you intended to do that but had a copy/paste error<sup>1</sup>.

```
$channel->publish(
  queue       => 'test',
  exchange    => 'testest', # <-- here
  routing_key => '',
  # ...
  on_ack          => sub { 
  _on_publish_message_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ );
  },
);
```

One more thing is that the `sleep` call in `_on_publish_message_success` is not a good idea when you are working with AnyEvent as that will stop the whole program. Use an [`AE::timer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AE#w-AE::timer-after-interval-cb) instead.

```
my $t; 
$t = AE::timer(1,0,sub {
  _publish_message( $condvar, $ar, $channel, 'Hello, world! Again ' . time );
  undef $t;
});
```

---

Here is the full code with all the changes.

```
use strictures 2;

use AnyEvent::RabbitMQ;

main();

############################################################################
sub main {
  _log( debug => 'main' );
  my $condvar = AnyEvent->condvar;
  my $ar      = AnyEvent::RabbitMQ->new;
  $ar->load_xml_spec;
  _log( debug => 'Connecting to RabbitMQ...' );
  $ar->connect(
    host            => 'localhost',
    port            => 5672,
    user            => 'guest',
    pass            => 'guest',
    vhost           => '/guest',
    timeout         => 1,
    tls             => 0,
    on_success      => sub { _on_connect_success( $condvar, $ar, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure', @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return', @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close', @_ ) },
  );
  $condvar->recv;
  $ar->close;
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_connect_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $new_ar ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Connected to RabbitMQ.' );
  _open_channel( $condvar, $new_ar );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _open_channel {
  my ( $condvar, $ar ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Opening RabbitMQ channel...' );
  $ar->open_channel(
    on_success => sub { _on_open_channel_success( $condvar, $ar, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_open_channel_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Opened RabbitMQ channel.' );
  $channel->confirm;
  _declare_exchange( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _declare_exchange {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declaring RabbitMQ exchange...' );
  $channel->declare_exchange(
    exchange        => 'testest',
    type            => 'fanout',
    on_success =>
      sub { _on_declare_exchange_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_declare_exchange_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declared RabbitMQ exchange.' );
  _bind_exchange( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _bind_exchange {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Binding RabbitMQ exchange...' );
  $channel->bind_exchange(
    source      => 'testest',
    destination => 'testest',
    routing_key => '',
    on_success => sub { _on_bind_exchange_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_bind_exchange_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Binded RabbitMQ exchange.' );
  _declare_queue( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}


############################################################################
sub _declare_queue {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declaring RabbitMQ queue...' );
  $channel->declare_queue(
    queue       => 'test',
    auto_delete => 1,
    passive     => 0,
    durable     => 0,
    exclusive   => 0,
    no_ack      => 1,
    ticket      => 0,
    on_success =>
      sub { _on_declare_queue_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_declare_queue_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Declared RabbitMQ queue.' );
  _bind_queue( $condvar, $ar, $channel );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _bind_queue {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Binding RabbitMQ queue...' );
  $channel->bind_queue(
    queue       => 'test',
    exchange    => 'testest',
    routing_key => '',
    on_success => sub { _on_bind_queue_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_bind_queue_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => 'Binded RabbitMQ queue.' );
  _log( info  => 'Master ready to publish messages.' );
  _publish_message( $condvar, $ar, $channel, 'Hello, world!' );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _publish_message {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel, $message ) = @_;
  _log( debug => "Publishing RabbitMQ message ($message)..." );
  $channel->publish(
    queue       => 'test',
    exchange    => 'testest',
    routing_key => '',
    body        => $message,
    header      => {},
    mandatory   => 0,
    immediate   => 0,
    on_success =>
      sub { _on_publish_message_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ ) },
    on_failure      => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'failure',      @_ ) },
    on_read_failure => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'read_failure', @_ ) },
    on_return       => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'return',       @_ ) },
    on_close        => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'close',        @_ ) },
    on_ack          => sub { 
        _on_publish_message_success( $condvar, $ar, $channel, @_ );
#        _error( $condvar, $ar, 'ack',          @_ )    
    },
    on_nack         => sub { _error( $condvar, $ar, 'nack',         @_ ) },
  );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _on_publish_message_success {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $channel ) = @_;
  _log( debug => "Published RabbitMQ message." );
  my $t; $t=AE::timer(1,0,sub {
      _publish_message( $condvar, $ar, $channel, 'Hello, world! Again ' . time );
      undef $t;
  });
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _error {
  my ( $condvar, $ar, $type, @error ) = @_;
  _log( error => sprintf '%s - %s', $type, join ', ', @error );
  $condvar->send( $condvar, $ar, $type, @error );
  return;
}

############################################################################
sub _log {
  my ( $level, $message ) = @_;
  my @time = gmtime time;
  $time[5] += 1900;
  $time[4] += 1;
  my $time = sprintf '%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d+00:00', @time[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ];
  my @caller0    = caller(0);
  my @caller1    = caller(1);
  my $subroutine = $caller1[3];
  $subroutine =~ s/^$caller0[0]:://;
  print STDERR "$time [$level] $message at $caller0[1] line $caller0[2] ($subroutine; from $caller1[1] line $caller1[2])\n";
  return;
}
```

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> In some places you need to buy your colleagues a beer for those :)</sup>

Comment: Hi. Do you know how to tune `heartbeat`? I have tried [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::RabbitMQ), but code takes value from server frame. It is 60 seconds and I do not know how to change that =(

Comment: @EugenKonkov it's been years since I touched this stuff. That was two jobs ago I'm afraid. I think you should ask a new question.